# How to read elements from a line in VHDL?

Tags: file-io, vhdl

I'm trying to use VHDL to read from a file that can have different formats. I know you're supposed to use the following two lines of code to read a line at a time, the read individual elements in that line.

```
readline(file, aline);
read(aline, element);
```

However my question is what will `read(aline, element)` return into `element`? What will it return if the line is empty? What will it return if I've used it let's say 5 times and my line only has 4 characters?

The reason I want to know is that if I am reading a file with an arbitrary number of spaces between valid data, how do I parse this valid data?

The file contains ASCII characters separated by arbitrary amounts of white space (any number of spaces, tabs, or new lines). If the line starts with a # that line is a comment and should be ignored.

Outside of these comments, the first part of the file contains characters that are only letters or numbers in combinations of variable size. In other words this:

```
123           ABC   12ABB3
```

However, the majority of the file (after a certain number of read words) will be purely numbers of arbitrary length, separated by an arbitrary amount of white space. In other words, the second part of the file is this:

```
255 0       2245   625         430
2222  33        111111
```

and I must be able to parse these numbers (and interpret them as such) individually.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.4 Package TEXTIO, para 8 (in part) *The READ procedures defined for a given type other than CHARACTER and STRING begin by skipping leading whitespace characters. A whitespace character is defined as a space, a nonbreaking space, or a horizontal tabulation character (SP, NBSP, or HT). For all READ procedures, characters are then removed from L and composed into a string representation (see 5.7) of the value of the specified type.*

Comment: How do I access this online?

Comment: [IEEE - Publications](https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/index.html) see [Purchasing Documents](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplorehelp/#/accessing-content/purchasing-documents).

Comment: Yeah I checked how to purchase it through IEEE but I can't afford it. Shouldn't a reference manual for a language be available for free? It's kind of ridiculous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read from a specific line from a text file in VHDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184087/how-to-read-from-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-vhdl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, all the `read` procedures in `std.textio` and `ieee.std_logic_textio` skip over leading spaces apart from the `character` and `string` versions (because a space is as much a character as any other).

You can test whether a `line` variable (the buffer) is empty like this:

```
if L'length > 0 then
```

where `L` is your `line` variable. There is also a set of overloaded `read` procedures with an extra status output:

```
procedure read (L    : inout LINE;
                VALUE: out   <type> ;
                GOOD : out   BOOLEAN);
```

The extra output - `GOOD` - is `true` if the read was successful and `false` if it wasn't. The advantage of these if that the read is unsuccessful, the simulation does not stop (as it does with the regular procedures). Also, with the versions in `std.textio`, if the read is unsuccessful, the read is non-destructive (ie whatever you were trying to read remains in the buffer). This is not the case with the versions in `ieee.std_logic_textio`, however.

If you really do not know what format you are trying to read, you could read the entire line into a string, like this:

```
variable S : string(1 to <some big number>);
...
readline(F, L);
assert L'length < S'length;  -- make sure S is big enough
S := (others => ' '); -- make sure that the previous line is overwritten
if L'length > 0 then
  read(L, S(1 to L'length);
end if;
```

The line `L` is now in the string `S`. You can then write some code to parse it. You may find the *type attribute* `'value` useful. This converts a string to some type, eg

```
variable I : integer;
...
I := integer'value(S(12 to 14));
```

would set integer `I` to the value contained in elements 12 to 14 of string `S`.

Another approach, as suggested by user1155120 below, is to peek at the values in the buffer, eg

```
if L'length > 0 then  -- check that the L isn't empty, otherwise the next line blows up
  if L.all(1) = '#' then
    -- the first character of the line is a '#' so the line must be a comment
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! So how do I know what type to set to my variable? I want to be able to ignore white space characters but at the same time not every line I read will have only numbers separated by white space (although the majority of them will be). In other words, I'm reading a file with variable format. The file could have comments (which are lines that start with a # character) and the file could also on rare occasion have letters. For the most part though the file is made up of numbers separated by arbitrary amounts of white space.

Comment: Your comment demonstrates your question is unclear. You're implying parsing (characterizing lines) which can be done on the value accessed by aline. 8.3 Selected names *For a selected name that is used to denote the object designated by an access value, the suffix shall be the reserved word all. The prefix shall belong to an access type.* You could ignore lines beginning with "#" or otherwise characterize the content of a line.

Comment: Sorry what I meant to ask was how do I know what type to set the variable I am passing to the read() function to? GIven the make up of the file I described, I want to be able to parse the elements separated by white space but know that the elements may not be of the same type. If I use read(aline, element), what type should I make the variable element?

Comment: By the way I sincerely appreciate your responses, I have an assignment due on Monday worth 20% of my grade and the class has no TA or professor who knows VHDL so we are completely on our own.

Comment: I assume my only option is to read each character individually and decide what to do with it based on how I want to parse my data?

Comment: Well, if the first character defines a comment line you can just check that. You haven't adequately describe how to distinguish between different classes of lines, or what their payload is.

Comment: @Omnomnious I have added some more stuff. The stuff in my answer is pretty advanced VHDL. Some is from our 'Advanced' course, some from our 'Expert' course. I would not have thought that it would be necessary to know such stuff on a course "taught" by a professor who didn't even know VHDL. Are you sure you're not overthinking this?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I'm pretty sure I'm not overthinking it. It's a 400 level course and the prof is known to demand a lot of effort and independent learning from students. I refined my description and I think the way to do it is as follows: For the part of the file with elements of letters mixed with numbers of variable length, I must read each character to parse words by using whitespace as delimiters. For the numbers of variable length I can just use the read(line, intVar) funtion to read individual integers regardless of intlength / whitespace. Is there a simpler way to do it?